# syntax highlight error (only at startup of line)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, syntax, richtextbox

I used this code (source = youtube)

It works fine but only problem is it is not highlighting first character of line after ( **line 0**)

My code :

```
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim selectionlength As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionLength
        Dim selectionstart As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
        Dim letter As String = String.Empty
        Do Until letter = " " Or RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart -= 1
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength += 1
            letter = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart, 1)
        Loop
        If RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Hello" Or RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " Hello" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.HotPink
        ElseIf RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Dinesh" Or RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " Dinesh" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Peru
        Else
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White
        End If
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionstart
        RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White
    End If
```

Output is : [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5CJ0.png)

You can see output from attached screenshot.

Green arrows (drawn by me) point out the word **Hello** and **Dinesh** are not highlighting.

**I used several techniques like Fastcolored text box which I like the most but I want to work on this very simple method because my program is not much big.**

Please give me some idea where I will need to make changes.

You can answer in vb.net or either in c#.

Thanks in advance.

**This is window-form application not WPF**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem :

```
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim selstrt As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
        Dim charc As String = String.Empty
        Dim first = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine
        Do Until charc = " " Or RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0 OrElse RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = first
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - 1
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = RichTextBox1.SelectionLength + 1
            charc = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart, 1)
        Loop
        If RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Hello" Or RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " Hello" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.HotPink
        ElseIf RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Dinesh" Or RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " Dinesh" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.LightGreen
        Else
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White
        End If
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = selstrt
        RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `Do Until letter = " " Or RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0`

A simple step through using the debugger and looking at the values would reveal this pretty quickly. It would have showed you that (using the word Hello) when selectionstart is 0 the loop ends but you still need to process that loop once more because at the point that it moves back to 0 you are only on the e. A solution to this is to change this to a Loop Until.

```
        Do
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart -= 1
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength += 1
            letter = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart, 1)
        Loop Until letter = " " Or letter Or = vbLf Or RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
```

Now the next problem you have is that on the second line, you will not reach 0 " " but you want to end searching there so you need to include a test for vbLf (a linefeed character when happens when someone hits enter to move to a new line.

Now that you have a new stopping point, you will then need to include that in your check for changing color

```
    If RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Hello" OrElse RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " Hello" OrElse RichTextBox1.SelectedText = vbLf & "Hello" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.HotPink
    ElseIf RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "Dinesh" OrElse RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " Dinesh" OrElse RichTextBox1.SelectedText = vbLf & "Dinesh" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Peru
    Else
```

As you can see, this is going to become a huge block of code as you add new commands and rules to it. For example, you have an issues with punctuation. This code will not colorize Dinesh in the following example:
`Hello is your name Dinesh?` because of the ?

One other way I've seen code formatting done is to scan the current line that the user is on against a list of known keywords and then format the line according to your format rules for any found keywords. Because there is a way to search partial text (ie, find Dinesh in Dinesh?) this will reduce code.

Edit: Also, forgot to mention. This code will crash if the first character is a Space, Enter or Backspace. Do you know why? it's a simple fix so I'll leave it for you to solve.

Comment: If i WILL use search technique then it will also highlight **ello** and as well as **Buffelo**. That I not want just for example.

Comment: Otherwise thanks for your answer it will create some problem but still I vote up.